# Power designer, generate procedures before tables

Tags: sql, powerdesigner

I am using Power Designer to create a database model. In one of my tables, I have created a Check constraint that calls a function to validate the attribute. The script for my table creation looks like this

```
   create table tbl_Inventory (
      Id      int                  identity,
      Name    VARCHAR(50)          not null
      constraint CK_Inventory_Name check (([dbo].[fn_CheckNameComplexLogic]([Name]) = 1)),
      constraint PK_Inventory primary key (Id),
   )
```

I have also created a function `fn_CheckNameComplexLogic` that performs the check.

When I try to use the code generation tool by going Database->Generate Database. The generated code always place `create table` before `create function`. Because my table depends on the function, the scripts always errors out. I could manually edit the generated code, but I am wondering if there is a place in PowerDesigner for configuring this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If may be a little overkill, but you can change the Generation Order to put (all) the functions (included in the `Procedure` category) before the `Table`.

- embed the DBMS in your model with `Database>Change Current DBMS`
- edit it with `Database>Edit Current DBMS`
- change the order in the `Script\Objects\GenerationOrder` item (using the XML view)
- put `Procedure` above `Table`

Comment: I've tried before to add a Tracibility Link from the Table to the "Procedure", but it did not change anything to the generation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add condition into Additional Checks of column properties tab after all constructs like %MINMAX% and %LISTVAL% and %CASE% and %RULES% and write here your condition ...